# js working only partially when migrated from jquery 1.4.1 to 1.9.1

Tags: jquery

I am really new to programming. So please apologize if you find my question silly.

When I click a tab a table appears. That is the idea.

I have a js working perfectly fine like how I want when i include

jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js

When I click on the tab it tab moves and a table appears, refer below link

http://smartdentalgroup.co.uk/test1/schedule.html

but it works only partially when I include

jquery-1.9.1.min.js

when i click on the tab  it moves but the table doesn't appear

http://smartdentalgroup.co.uk/test1/schedule_1.html

The only difference is in the jquery.
Can somebody please, help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're using some deprecated or completely removed functions or features
that is not compatible between two version.

One possible solution is to use **[jQuery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)** plugin which is used to detect and restore APIs or features that have been deprecated in jQuery and removed as of version 1.9

In your web page, load this plugin after the script for jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly; If I were you I would be using the very latest version of jQuery (While your upgrading). You are going to have to debug/make changes when upgrading anyway, might as well save yourself a bit of time later on and use the latest version. [Link is here. Use the 1.11.0 opposed to the 2.1.0](http://jquery.com/download/) (As that version does not support some older browsers).

Now secondly, download Chrome (if you havn't already) go to your page and hit "Control + Shift + I". This will open Chrome debugging tools; Which are fantastic. You can see everything from the "real time" DOM layout to what errors are being through from the console.

You will be having these bugs because your code is using 'out-of-date' jQuery functions, this is a good way to start looking for them.

It may also be both looking at the jQuery 'upgrade plugin' as suggested, however I never had great luck with that. In the end, I read through the patch notes and made changes manually.

Goodluck :)

Note: Just had a look through your page. Not sure if its a preference sort of thing, but I normally load my javaScript in the `<HEAD>` section of the HTML document.